# "A GKScore must specify a leaderboard."

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, game-center

Has anyone come across this error when trying to integrate Game Center into an iOS 7 App?

> A GKScore must specify a leaderboard.

Here is the code where it fails:

```
if(points > 0)
{
    //Fails on the next line
    [self.gameCenterManager reportScore:points forCategory:self.currentLeaderBoard];
}
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != NULL) {
    leaderboardController.category = self.currentLeaderBoard;
    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek; 
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**UPDATE** I have tried another method and still get the same error.

Other Method:

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:self.currentLeaderBoard];
scoreReporter.value = points;

[scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil)
    {
        [self showAlert:@"Game Center Error" theMessage:@"There was a problem uploading your score to Game Center, if this problem persists, please contact JApp Design." alertTag:0];
    }
}];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in `[self.gameCenterManager reportScore:points forCategory:self.currentLeaderBoard];`, does `self.leaderboard` equal the leaderboard ID you created in itunes connect?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method of reporting scores appears to be deprecated with the introduction of iOS 7.0

Here is the code that will fix the problem:

```
        GKScore *reportScore = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:@"leaderBoardI"];
        reportScore.value = totalPoints;

        NSArray *scores = @[reportScore, nil];

        [GKScore reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue with you but I solved my issue..

Here is my original code.

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier: identifier];
scoreReporter.value = score;
scoreReporter.context = 0;
scoreReporter.shouldSetDefaultLeaderboard = YES;
NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];

[GKScore reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    //Do something interesting here.
    [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(scoreReported:) withArg: NULL error: error];
}];
```

From here, I removed the line.  `scoreReporter.shouldSetDefaultLeaderboard = YES`
So it worked fine.