# App crashes on Game Center score submit, only on App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

Crash log:
A `GKScore` must specify a `leaderboard`.

When I try it in `sandbox`, it works ok, in `App Store` version it crashes.

```
- (void)reportScoreToGameCenter
{
    NSString *totalPoints = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TotalPointsUserDefaultsKey];
    GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:[GCHelper sharedInstance].leaderboardIdentifier];
    score.value = [totalPoints integerValue];

    [GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
//        if (error != nil) {
//            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
//        }
    }];
}
```

`LeaderboardIdentifier` is obtained via:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Leaderboard identifier: %@", leaderboardIdentifier);
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else{
                self.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
            }
        }];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273320/a-gkscore-must-specify-a-leaderboard

Comment: @Omer, I saw that, it is the exact way I'm using it

Comment: Did you check what are you getting back in `loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler`? Is that a valid leaderboard on iTunes Connect?